# 'An nlobjSearchColumn contains an invalid column, or is not in proper syntax' in NetSuite

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I'm really new to NetSuite, so I'm sure this is something silly I'm doing wrong, but I'm trying to look up the most recent check number for an Account in a script.  So I'm setting up a search on the CustomerPayment table, for the checkNum column.  I'm doing that like this:

```
var acct = nlapiGetFieldValue('account');
var paymentFilters = new Array();
paymentFilters[0] = new nlobjSearchFilter('account', null, 'anyof', acct);

var paymentColumns = new Array();
paymentColumns[0] = new nlobjSearchColumn('checknum');

var paymentSearchResults = nlapiSearchRecord('customerpayment', null, paymentFilters, paymentColumns);
```

But I'm getting a "An nlobjSearchColumn contains an invalid column, or is not in proper syntax: checknum" error.  I verified that there is a CustomerPayment table, and there is also a checkNum column within it.  At least the Record Browser seems to suggest that. (also the first time I'm using that) I also verified that acct contains the value I'm expecting it to.

I've done a couple other searches, using basically the same code and they seem to work as expected, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  For example, this code seems to work:

```
    var filters = new Array();
    filters[0] = new nlobjSearchFilter('account', null, 'anyof', acct);

    var columns = new Array();
    columns[0] = new nlobjSearchColumn('tranid');

    var searchResults = nlapiSearchRecord('check', null, filters, columns);
```

Anyway, any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

checknum is not searchable. Try with otherrefnum like this:

```
var acct = nlapiGetFieldValue('account');
var paymentFilters = new Array();
paymentFilters[0] = new nlobjSearchFilter('account', null, 'anyof', acct);

var paymentColumns = new Array();
paymentColumns[0] = new nlobjSearchColumn('otherrefnum');

var paymentSearchResults = nlapiSearchRecord('customerpayment', null, paymentFilters, paymentColumns);
```

Comment: That did it thanks. Apparently I was looking at the incorrect list in the Records Browser.  After seeing your code snippet, and reading Mike's comments below, I saw what I was doing.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

While `checknum` is a valid field on the `customerpayment` record, it's not a valid search result column.

This document outlines all of the scriptable fields for customer payments and `checknum` is not listed in the Search Columns section.

[NetSuite Record Browser](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2016_1/script/record/customerpayment.html)

I don't see that that Check Number is available when performing a search.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I wasn't looking in the Search Fields list in the Records Browser.  I appreciate the help.

Answer (score -1):

It is a rare error, because the column name is indeed correct. You could solve it like this:

```
var filters = new Array();
filters[0] = new nlobjSearchFilter('account', null, 'anyof', acct);

var paymentColumns = new Array();
paymentColumns[0] = new nlobjSearchColumn('internalId');

var paymentSearchResults = nlapiSearchRecord('customerpayment', null, filters, paymentColumns);

for (var i = 0; paymentSearchResults != null && i < paymentSearchResults.length; i++) {

    var customerpayment = nlapiLoadRecord('customerpayment', paymentSearchResults[i].getValue('internalId'));
    var checknum = customerpayment.getFieldValue('checknum');

    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'checknum', checknum);
}
```